# Confirm message upon gridview update

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I'm having one gridview which is bound to dataset and set the 'AutoGenerateEditButton' to true.
When user click 'Edit', there is two options available as usual ('Update'/'Cancel'). 
Once user did some changes on gridview data and click 'Update', I want to show confirm message (eight client/server). If user click 'No', abort the server event (RowUpdating). 
If user choose 'yes', call server event to update into database.

Gridview would look like this:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUserList" runat="server" GridLines="None"
                Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvUserList_RowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowEditing="gvUserList_RowEditing" OnRowDataBound="gvUserList_RowDataBound"
                OnRowUpdating="gvUserList_RowUpdating" AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
```

At code behind, gridview will bind with dataset.

```
gvUserList.DataSource = ds;
gvUserList.DataMember = "ExistingUsers";
gvUserList.DataBind();
```

I have google around and there are confirm message for gridview delete action. Nothing found for update action.

Appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You should not use use `AutoGenerateEditButton`, but instead a template

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function ConfirmOnDelete(){
   return confirm("Are you sure to delete the item?")==true)
  }
</script>
```

**Template Field**

The `LinkDelete_Click` is the server-side method to invoke to delete your item

```
<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID=" LinkDelete " runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("YourPrimaryKey") %>' OnClientClick="return ConfirmOnDelete();">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**C#**

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, 
                         GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
  {
    // get the primary key id of the clicked row
    int id= Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    // Delete the record 
    DeleteRecordByPrimaryKey(id);// Implement this on your own :) 

  }
}
```

Take a look to this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12666/GridView-Delete-with-Confirmation) to another approach

Comment: With this method, I can call the confirm message. But one more requirement is there. If user click 'Yes' on message, then update server event to be trigger. However, if user click 'No/Cancel', then update server event not suppose to trigger. How can I achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: My templatefield is look like below:-                   <ItemTemplate>
<asp:linkbutton id="lbtnEdit" runat="server" commandname="Edit" text="Edit" />
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>                                
<asp:linkbutton id="btnUpdate" runat="server" commandname="Update" text="Update" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to update?');"/>
<asp:linkbutton id="btnCancel" runat="server" commandname="Cancel" text="Cancel" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel the changes?');"/></EditItemTemplate>

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have amend it for update command instead and it's working as I needed. Have a nice weekend ahead! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using RowDataBound event. Also make sure the control type and control location.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        LinkButton lb = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
        lb.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure want to update?');";
    }
}
```

In this code, my update button is a LinkButton which is in First Cell, first control.